# Need some clarification on JSONP with JQuery/WCF

Tags: jquery, wcf, json, jsonp

Goal: Expose a simple WCF service that would take as a parameter a string that was a username and see if it already existed. This service would be used on the registration page of the site I'm working on so when a user typed a username it would automatically check to see if it was taken.

I've actually gotten this functionality to work, but I had to enable crossDomainScripting for the WCF service. My question is "why?"

To the code!

My WCF service is hosted within my MVC3 site (I originally had it in a separate site but to remove any and all concern about cross site scriptiong I moved it local.)

Interface for WCF Service

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IMembershipServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "IsUsernameAvailable/{username}",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    MembershipUserAvailability IsUsernameAvailable(string username);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "helloto/{name}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string Hello(string name);
}
```

Implementation:

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
    = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MembershipServices : IMembershipServices
{
    #region IMembershipServices Members

    public string Hello(string name)
    {
        return String.Format("Hello:{0}", name);
    }


    public MembershipUserAvailability IsUsernameAvailable(string username)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(username);
        }

        MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(username, false);

        var membershipUserAvailability = new MembershipUserAvailability
                                             {
                                                 UserName = username,
                                                 IsAvailable = membershipUser == null ? true : false
                                             };

        return membershipUserAvailability;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <!-- This section is optional with the default configuration
    model introduced in .NET Framework 4 -->
        <service name="MedicalPracticeWeb.Services.MembershipServices" behaviorConfiguration="MembershipServicesBehaviors">

            <!-- This endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc  -->
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingJsonP" contract="MedicalPracticeWeb.Services.IMembershipServices" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" />

            <!-- The mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/mex -->
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MembershipServicesBehaviors">
                <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttpBindingJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"></binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Jquery to imlement call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var usernameTextbox = $('#username');
var usernameUnavailableRow = $('#usernameUnavailableRow');
var availabilityMessage = $('#availabilityMessage');

usernameTextbox.blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {

        $.getJSON('/Services/MembershipServiceHost.svc/IsUsernameAvailable/' + escape($(this).val()), function (results) {
            if (results.IsAvailable) {
                if (usernameUnavailableRow.is(':visible')) {
                    availabilityMessage.html('This username is available.');
                    availabilityMessage.addClass('usernameAvailable');
                    availabilityMessage.removeClass('usernameTaken');
                }
            }
            else {
                usernameUnavailableRow.show();
                availabilityMessage.html('This username is already taken!');
                availabilityMessage.addClass('usernameTaken');
                availabilityMessage.removeClass('usernameAvailable');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

});

Now this all works great. I can type a username into the textbox on my registration form and when I leave the field the onBlur event fires and calls the WCF service returning results as expected...but *only* if I have crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" in my web.config. This puzzles me. Perhaps it's a lack of understanding of JSON and JSONP (entirely possible. I'm fairly new to working with JSON) but since the service is hosted in the same domain why would I need this set?

I took a look at what Fiddler was sending:

GET /Services/MembershipServiceHost.svc/IsUsernameAvailable/Tim?callback=jQuery1510988704698288691_1302393437642&_=1302393485350 HTTP/1.1

And there's the callback parameter that I see mentioned in the JQuery docs.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

Does this mean the simple act of having an on success callback will force GetJSON to utilize JSONP?

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean the simple act of
>   having an on success callback will
>   force GetJSON to utilize JSONP?

The simple answer is yes.

If you add in the parameter or set the type to jsonp, jQuery will auto-magically do all the hard work for you.  You also need your service to be smart enough to wrap the data in a function call before it sends it to you -- but .net does this if given the parameter.

There are a number of other answers on SO that talk about how to use jsonp via jQuery.